# How to solve error with 2D labels in partial fit regression problems?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I would like to use continual learning (incremental learning) in my code. The dataset is composed of cartesian coordinates in which X and y is the same. I've solved the fact of using a 2D in the y with this simple solution.

```
X = raw[:-1]
y = raw[1:]
```

Mention these two lines above allow that both latitude and longitude can be used as data and label.

This solution works using regular scikit learn regression techniques such as RF, LR, etc. during training fit, however, when applying the same solution into partial_fit, I get this error:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (9, 2) instead.
```

This is the code:

```
#!pip install haversine
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import haversine as hs
from haversine import Unit
num=10

i=1

while((i*num+1)<len(10)):
  raw= dat[0:(i*num)]
  X = raw[:-1]
  y = raw[1:]
  regressor = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3, random_state=42)
  #regressor = LinearRegression()
  regressor.partial_fit(X, y)

  pred=regressor.predict([raw[(i*num)-1]])
  hs.haversine(( pred[0,0] , pred[0,1] ),( dat[(i*num),0] , dat[(i*num),1] ), unit=Unit.METERS)
  i=i+1
```

The data can be obtained from here:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

content = """latitude(m) longitude(m)
41.392245 2.162762
41.392261 2.162783
41.392292 2.162825
41.392340 2.162888
41.392369 2.162943
41.392405 2.163008
41.392454 2.163093
41.392520 2.163186
41.392600 2.163296
41.392687 2.163417"""

# Create a file-like object from the content string
file_obj = io.StringIO(content)

# Load the content into a DataFrame
raw = pd.read_csv(file_obj, delimiter='\t' or ' ')
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It is complaining about your `y` having two columns. Why does it have two columns?

Comment: Thanks @Cryo, since coordinates are unique pair of lat/lon, I cannot apply a label to each cartesian coordinates

Comment: Well, the error message seems to suggest that the tool you chose expects a single label, not two. So you need to choose a suitable tool.